# strange ob_start() behaviour - double output

Tags: php, output-buffering

ob_start() doesn't seem to be stopping any output so when I flush the buffer it's doubling up

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "Text..... <br />";
echo ob_get_flush();
?>
```

Outputs

```
Text..... 
Text.....
```

But I was expecting

```
Text.....
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the echo on the last line.

`ob_get_flush()` implicitly prints the stored output and also returns it so you're printing it out twice.

You may have confused `ob_get_flush()` with `ob_get_clean()`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "Text..... <br />";
ob_get_flush();
?>
```

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php

> Flush the output buffer, return it as a string and turn off output buffering

Flush the output means: it sends the output to the browser or the commandline.
return the string means: it returns the string, so you can store the flushed string in a variable. And since you're `echo`ing this string you get the output a second time.